# C++: Chaos Game: Pyramid aligning points to be drawn correctly

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I am having a little trouble - I understand the algorithm of the chaos game, got 3 points, set up in a pyramid form. The rest is is easy, just take the current point and a random roll of 1-3 and move halfway from the current point to either a,b or c, depending on the roll. But I am having difficulty with (as you can see in the picture outlined in red) the points plot correctly but just goes straight  up. How do I get it to align towards top of the pyramid?

Maybe it is easier to use a GLine that got four parameters for this (x,y,x,y)?

[image]

[image]

```
double playGame(double newPointX, double &newPointY, GWindow &display)
{

int roll = randomInteger(DICE_LOW, DICE_HIGH);

// WEST
if (roll == 1) {

}

// EAST
else if (roll == 2) {


}
// NORTH

else if (roll == 3 && newPointY > LIMIT) {
    display.drawOval(newPointX,
                     POINT_NORTH + (newPointY / 2),
                     1, 1);

    newPointY =  (newPointY / 2);
    cout << newPointY << endl;
    return newPointX;
}

return NULL;
```

}

Comment: Are you asking how do you make it follow the line connecting the lower-left and upper points of the pyramid?

Comment: And is the code of an east/west roll irrelevant here?

Comment: yes, if it rolls North it needs to follow the points of the pyramid. North,East,West just means it goes halfway towards either point from current point depending on roll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't changing your x position. You could do this by calculating the inverse slope of the line between the start point and the end point( top of the pyramid ).

Just use something like:

```
float inverseSlope = (xTop - xLeft) / (yTop - yLeft);
```

Then your calculation for the x position would be:

```
xPosition = (yPosition * inverseSlope) + xLeft; //xLeft being your start position
```

This is without your variables of course but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Dammit! I need to take an Algebra and Calculus class before delving deeper into algorithmic thought.

Comment: It's important to understand some basic algebraic concepts for some algorithms but for many others just a fair amount of logic can get you through.